# Referencing a variable in a riverpod notifier and a top level function

Tags: flutter

I am relatively new  to flutter and I have a problem that is starting to test my patience - I am hoping somebody would be able to help me please.

I am trying to monitor sms messages coming in to android phone and update a list on a screen in an app. I am using riverPod and this seems to be working correctly because I can print a value from within a method called by a consumer. I think it is a problem with the variable scope because the values I am passing in seem to be blank.

With this code I can see 'Updated State' on the console but the state is a blank array:

```
class EventDynamicNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Event>> {
  EventDynamicNotifier() : super([]);

  void addEvent(Event event) {

    state = [...state, event];
  }
  void changeEvents(List<Event> eventList){
    state=[...eventList];
    print('updated state');
    print(state);
  }
}

final eventDynamicProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<EventDynamicNotifier, List<Event>>((ref) {
  return EventDynamicNotifier();
});
```

Here I can see the sms being received by the backGroundMessage Handler and the event being created and added to the eventList.  However when the timer fires - the list it passes seems to be blank.  The periodic timer was something I implemented to try and get round the issue I was having - I was trying to call the stateNotifer method from within the backGroundMessageHandler but the ref variable wasn't available there.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import 'package:sms_receiver/models/event.dart';

import 'package:telephony/telephony.dart';

import 'package:sms_receiver/screens/logs.dart';

import 'package:sms_receiver/widgets/main_drawer.dart';

import 'package:sms_receiver/providers/events_provider.dart';

List<Event> eventList = [];

backgroundMessageHandler(SmsMessage message) async {
  final event = Event(
      id: "new",
      category: "c2",
      customerTelephoneNumber: message.address.toString(),
      customerName: "Joe Blogs",
      time: DateTime.now(),
      workProfileName: "TBA",
      message: message.body.toString());
  eventList.add(event);
  print(event);
  print(eventList);
}

class TabsScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const TabsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<TabsScreen> createState() {
    return _TabsScreenState();
  }
}

class _TabsScreenState extends ConsumerState<TabsScreen> {
  Timer? timer;
  int count = 0;

  void _selectButton(int index) {
    print(index);
  }

  void _setScreen(String identifier) async {}
  @override
  void initState() {
    int eventListCount=0;
    Telephony telephony = Telephony.instance;
    telephony.requestPhoneAndSmsPermissions;
    telephony.listenIncomingSms(
      onNewMessage: (SmsMessage message) {
        print("forground");
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: backgroundMessageHandler,
    );

    /// Initialize a periodic timer with 1 second duration
    timer = Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 10),
      (timer) {
        /// callback will be executed every 1 second, increment a count value
        /// on each callback
        print('timer fired');
        print("eventListCount $eventListCount");
        print("eventList.length ${eventList.length}");
        //if(eventListCount != eventList.length){
        print('inside For');
        //   setState(() {
        //     count++;
        // });
        ref.read(eventDynamicProvider.notifier).changeEvents(eventList);
        eventListCount = eventList.length;
        //}
      },
    );

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Read the provder
    final e = ref.watch(eventDynamicProvider);
    print("this is the new eventlist $e");
    
    Widget activePage = LogsScreen(
      eventList: e,
    );
    var activePageTitle = '';

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(activePageTitle),
      ),
      drawer: MainDrawer(
        onSelectScreen: _setScreen,
      ),
      body: activePage,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _selectButton,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.send_outlined),
            label: 'Send Now',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app_outlined),
            label: 'Quit',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.call_received),
            label: 'Recieve Now',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is a screen that I am using waiting the stateNotifier - I am expecting flutter to rebuild the widget when the stateNotifier updates but it is always a blank list because I cannot get it to update

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:sms_receiver/models/event.dart';
import 'package:sms_receiver/screens/log_details.dart';
import 'package:sms_receiver/widgets/filter_banner.dart';
import 'package:sms_receiver/providers/events_provider.dart';

class LogsScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const LogsScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.eventList,
  });
  final List<Event> eventList;
  @override
  ConsumerState<LogsScreen> createState() => _LogsScreenState();
}

class _LogsScreenState extends ConsumerState<LogsScreen> {

  var _isLoading = false;
  String? _error;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  }

  void _switchToDetails(event) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (ctx) => LogDetailsScreen(
          event: event,
        ),
      ),
    ); // Navigator.push(context, route)
  }

  void _removeItem(Event item) async {
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Watch the provider for updates and update
    final eventItems=ref.watch(eventDynamicProvider);

    Widget content = const Center(child: Text('No items added yet.'));

    if (_isLoading) {
      content = const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }

    print(eventItems);
    if (eventItems.isNotEmpty) {
      content = //const Center(
          Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          const FilterBanner(),          
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: eventItems.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Dismissible(
                onDismissed: (direction) {
                  _removeItem(eventItems[index]);
                },
                key: ValueKey(eventItems[index].id),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(eventItems[index].workProfileName),
                  leading: Container(
                    width: 24,
                    height: 24,
                    color: eventItems[index].category == 'c2'
                        ? Colors.red
                        : Colors.green,
                  ),
                  trailing: Text(
                    eventItems[index].time.toString(),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    print("tapped $index");
                    _switchToDetails(eventItems[index]);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
      //);
    }
    return content;
  }
}
```

It seems to me that the timer is using the blank eventList all the time rather than the updated eventList - I have tried lots of things but the eventList never seems to be visible in both the widget (so I can access the ref) or in the toplevel background message handler

Any feedback would be welcome :)

I tried declaring the eventList in different places.

I would like to update a list on a lower screen when an sms message is received